# Can I share a git folder between dual boot instances?

Tags: git, github

I dual boot (Windows/Ubuntu) on my laptop and I have a few git repos that I might work on from either.

Previously I would have had separate folders for each boot and used the traditional push/pull approach when working from each.

Is it possible (safe/stable) to have a single working folder and access it from both boots, and if so would I need to ensure I committed before switching?

Does it make a difference if I use an IDE (say Eclipse)?

Comment: Sounds pretty safe - you can always try it out for a while and see. Just make sure the editor you use is set to use the same line endings on both systems. An IDE won't make any difference to the git repository, but may have its own configuration stored in the repo directory that is platform specific.

Answer (score 2):

There's only two concerns: the Git version and line endings.

## Git version

The internal structure of a Git repository has changed some over the years. Using two different Git clients to work on the same clone *might* be a problem if they're very different versions. Best to be sure you're using a close to the same versions as possible in both Ubuntu and Windows.

## Line endings

This will be the biggest issue. If your Windows editor is using `crlf` and your Ubuntu is using `lf` things might get confused. This is a normal problem for working with a Git project on many platforms.

A simple fix is to add [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) to your project. This consists of putting an `.editorconfig` file at the top of your project and choosing a canonical line ending. For example...

```
# Unix-style newlines for every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
```

[Many editors recognize EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/#download). Others need a plugin.

This avoids yourself or anyone else having to worry about configuring their editor for your project, your EditorConfig will take care of it. It can also cover character sets, indentation, tabs-vs-spaces, final newlines, trailing whitespace... all those fiddly little whitespace issues that plague projects.